# How to set a meta-tag from a plugin

Tags: plugin-development, templating, plugins

I'm writing a Craft CMS plugin with a widget. This widget needs to make calls to the Github-API trough javascript ([Selectize](http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) is used in the widget). Now, the problem is that it's not allowed, made clear by this message in the console:

> Refused to connect to 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories/?q=i' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data:". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

I can fix this by setting the Content-Security-Policy meta tag in the head:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' https://api.github.com/">
```

I've attempted to add this with the following code in the template for my widget:

```
{% set meta %}
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' https://api.github.com/">
{% endset %}
{% includeHeadHtml(meta) %}
```

Is this correct or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

It looks as if there is a [Content-Security-Policy](https://content-security-policy.com/) header that may also do what you want. You should be able to use the [header](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/header) tag to set this:

```
{% header "script-src: 'self' https://api.github.com/;" %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this doesn't seem the work. first there's the internal server error "Unexpected character ";".", removing the ; and adding a " to the end resolves in a new error: Unexpected token "name" of value "script" ("end of statement block" expected). So kinda stuck here again :)

Comment: @IbeVanmeenen there was a typo in the original answer. give it a whirl again.

Comment: @MarionNewlevant Errors are gone now, but the issue is still there... The call is made by the Selectize.js plugin (http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/). So I'm not making al call trough php, but trough Javascript...